# Retrieve all distinct records from table and if any changes happen between two similar distinct record then need to consider both. Using select query

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, netezza

I want to convert table1 into table2. As I need to find out all distinct records excluding mis_date fro the table and most important  condition is if any changes happen between two similar distinct records than in that case I want both of them as two distinct records.

Example:

i/p

```
empId Empname Pancard MisDate 
123 alex ads234 31/11/2012 
123 alex ads234 31/12/2012 
123 alex ads234 31/01/2013 
123 alex dds124 29/02/2013 
123 alex ads234 31/03/2013 
123 alex ads234 31/04/2013 
123 alex dds124 30/05/2013
```

Expected o/p

```
empId Empname Pancard MisDate 
123 alex ads234 31/11/2012 
123 alex dds124 29/02/2013 
123 alex ads234 31/03/2013 
123 alex dds124 30/05/2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's only one row for each `MisDate` (otherwise you'll have to find another way to specify ordering):

```
SELECT t1.empId, t1.Empname, t1.Pancard
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t2 
    ON t2.MisDate = (SELECT MAX(MisDate) FROM Table1 t3 WHERE t3.MisDate < t1.MisDate)
WHERE t2.empId IS NULL 
OR t2.empId <> t1.empId OR t2.Empname <> t1.Empname OR t2.Pancard <> t1.Pancard
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fe74/1)

This performs a self-join on the previous record, as ordered by `MisDate`, outputting if it is different or if there is no previous record (it is the first row).

Note: You've got some funky dates. I assume these are just transcription errors and have corrected them in the fiddle.

Comment: Thx a lot for solving this problem. It's really appreciable because this query will help lot in data ware house project.